# Proving Countability with Character Encoding

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say I want to prove that there are a countable number of arithmetic expressions with rational numbers. I encode the digits 0-9 as 0-9, and then I encode (,),+,-,*,and / as A, B, C, D, E, and F, respectively. Then, for any algebraic expression I can find an integer in base-16 which corresponds to the expression. For example (4+5)*7+3 would map to A4C5EC3. Since this is a one-to-one correspondence, then we can say there are a countable number of rational arithmetic expressions.

My question: Is this a rigorous proof technique? It feels sort of like "cheating".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fine. If you have an alphabet $\Sigma$ of $n$ symbols (here with $n=16$), you can encode non-empty strings over $\Sigma$ of length $\ell$ as $\ell$-place integers in base $b$. If, as in the present setting, you actually care about only some of the possible strings, you’re still getting a subset of $\Bbb Z^+$, so you’re still showing that your set of strings is countable.

There is one minor technical detail that should be mentioned: in another setting you might also want to be able to encode the empty string of symbols. The simplest solution is to assign it the digit $0$ and work in base $n+1$.